# RxJS Pipe After Flatmap? Do Pipes subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to clean up some RxJs code and I have a few questions.
Looking at the code below.

a) If all I am doing is some manipulation inside of a pipe do I need to unsubscribe with a take(1)?

b) Is it ok to have a pipe after a flatmap inside of a pipe?

```html
const fetchServiceStatus$ = this.facade.fetchServiceStatus(e.sub).pipe(
      take(1),
      tap(
        (res) => {
          this.shareStatus = res;
          if (this.shareStatus.serviceStatus === '') {
            this.message.info('Not a Data Sharing Member');
          }
        },
        () => {
          this.message.error('Error Fetching Data Sharing Service Status');
        }
      )
    );
    const fetchAllGroupMemberDetails$ = fetchServiceStatus$
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((res) => res.serviceStatus !== ''),
        flatMap(() => this.facade.fetchAllGroupMemberDetails(e.sub))
      )
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        catchError((err) => {
          this.message.error(
            'Error Fetching Data Sharing Group Member Details'
          );
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        tap((res) => {
          this.allGroupMemberDetails = res;
          if (res.members.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < res.members.length; i++) {
              if (res.members[i].memberMDN === this.memberMDN) {
                this.currentMemberDetails = res.members[i];
              }
            }
          }
        })
      );
```

Comment: A pipable function is a function that take an input and returns a function that returns an observable. Best way to understand them is crack one open on Github. They are all open source and very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

take(1) will unsubscribe if the stream emits a value, you still have an orphan subscription if the stream did not emit. In Angular the common pattern is to use takeUntil with a subject and make that subject emit and complete in the ngOnDestroy.

Rather than using take(1) with a flatMap you can use a switchMap that unsubscribes from the higher order observable.

Tapping into the stream and setting properties on the component is notorious for causing the change detection exception, value changed after value was checked. It is best to use a derived observable and the async pipe.

Comment: Thanks. So I would still need a takeUntil in the pipe after the switchMap though correct? can it be done like this       .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.facade.fetchOtaRecord(this.subscriber.imsi)),
        take(1)
      )